# Check managed assembly version on an SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, managed-code

I need to find out the version of an assembly deployed to an SQL Server database.
I need to do it via script or other programmatic way to know if i need to redeploy the assembly.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help out..

> Syntax
>   *ASSEMBLYPROPERTY('assembly_name', 'property_name')*
>   **assembly_name**  Is the name of the assembly.
>
> **property_name**  Is the name of a property about which to retrieve
>   information. property_name can be one
>   of the following values.
>
> Value
>   **CultureInfo**   Locale of the assembly.
>   **PublicKey**   Public key or public key token of the assembly.
>   **MvID**   Complete, compiler-generated version
>   identification number of the assembly.
>
> **VersionMajor**   Major component (first part) of the four-part version
>   identification number of the assembly.
>
> **VersionMinor**   Minor component (second part) of the four-part version
>   identification number of the assembly.
>
> **VersionBuild**   Build component (third part) of the four-part version
>   identification number of the assembly.
>
> **VersionRevision**   Revision component (fourth part) of the
>   four-part version identification
>   number of the assembly.
>   **SimpleName**   Simple name of the assembly.
>   **Architecture**   Processor architecture of the assembly.
>   **CLRName**   Canonical string that encodes the simple name, version
>   number, culture, public key, and
>   architecture of the assembly. This
>   value uniquely identifies the assembly
>   on the common language runtime (CLR)
>   side.